# Includes in sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

When I use includes, the nested objects are stored in a field that is named after their model, not after their association.

I have an association like this:

```
account.hasMany(key,{'foreignKey':'owner'});
key.belongsTo(account,{'foreignKey':'owner'});
```

When I now request a few keys with findAll() and want to include their associated accounts, they end up in a new `account` field and not in the `owner` field.

When I use `as` in the associations AND/OR in the include, I get errors at definition time.

What I get from the findAll looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    owner:3,
    account:{id:3, ...}
  },
  {
    id:2,
    owner:123,
    account:{id:123, ...}
  }
]
```

What I want is:

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    owner:{id:3, ...}
  },
  {
    id:2,
    owner:{id:123, ...}
  }
]
```

-- update --

I tried it like this:

```
account.hasMany(key, {
  'as':'owner',
  'foreignKey':{
    'name':'owner_id',
    'field':'owner'
  }
})

key.belongsTo(account, {
  'as':'owner',
  'foreignKey':{
    'name':'owner_id',
    'field':'owner'
  }
})
```

With this query:

```
key.findAll({
  'where':{...},
  'include':account
})
```

But I now get the error that `account` isn't associated with `key`

--- edit 2 ---

If I configure the associations like this:

```
account.hasMany(key, {'foreignKey':'owner'});
key.belongsTo(account, {'foreignKey':'owner'});
```

And query them like that:

```
  key.findAll({
    where:...,
    include:{
      model:account,
      as:'owner'
    }
  });
```

I get the error: Possibly unhandled Error: account (owner) is not associated to key!

If I configure the associations like this:

```
account.hasMany(key, {'foreignKey':'owner'});
key.belongsTo(account, {'foreignKey':'owner'});
```

And query them like that:

```
  key.findAll({
    where:...,
    include:{
      model:account
    }
  });
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            ...
            "owner": 1,
            "account": {
                "id": 1,
                ...
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            ...
            "owner": 2,
            "account": {
                "id": 2,
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I configure the associations like this:

```
account.hasMany(key, {'as':'owner'});
key.belongsTo(account, {'as':'owner'});
```

And query them like that:

```
  key.findAll({
    where:...,
    include:{
      model:account,
      as:'owner'
    }
  });
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            ...
            "accountId": 1,
            "ownerId": 1,
            "owner":null

        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            ...
            "accountId": 2,
            "ownerId": 2,
            "owner":null
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems like all configurations I try either don't put the included records at the right place OR throw errors.

Comment: You can't name your association the same as the foreign key, they will clash. But you could perhaps use `foreignKey: {name: 'owner_id', field: 'owner'}` to fix this.

Comment: thank you, but this didn't work :\ made an edit for explanation

Comment: You need to use `include: [{model: account, as: 'owner'}]`

Comment: This does not work. I get "Possibly unhandled Error: account (owner) is not associated to key!" or `owner` in the response is empty or the `account` is under `account` and not owner.

Comment: edit with more examples

Comment: You had `key.belongsTo(account, {'as':'owner'});` right?